# How to disable left and right arrow keys for navigation in SWT List?

Tags: java, list, navigation, swt

The `SWT List` lets both `left` and `up` arrow keys to go up the list items and both `right` and `down` arrow keys to go down the list items by default. But I want to use `left` and `right` arrow keys for another propose. How can I remove the `left` and `right` arrow keys listener that is in `SWT List` by default? And then replace my own. Here is the code I want to use:

```
Listener listListener = new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            int RowIndex = listData.getSelectionIndex();

            if(RowIndex == 0){
                if (e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_RIGHT) { //right arrow
                    //do something
                }else if (e.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_LEFT) { //left arrow
                    //do something
                }
             }
         }
    };
    list.addListener(SWT.KeyDown, listListener);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress the *default behavior* of key strokes by setting the `doit` flag to `false` like this:

```
if( event.keyCode == SWT.ARROW_RIGHT ) {
  // do something    
  event.doit = false;
}
```

The default behavior of arrows keys is very likely platform dependant. Windows behaves as you describe, but other platforms might behave differently. Setting the `doit` flag to `false` will work in any case, whether the key has a default behavior or not.

I would rather not override platform behavior because your applications will then behave inconsistent with respect to the platforms general usage.

Comment: Thank you so much.. It works. Well, I agree with you, but in my case I develop a software for blind people and some functions have to be modified to suit special needs.